# Queryset API distinct() does not work?

Tags: python, django

```
class Message(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.ManyToManyField(Message, verbose_name='Discussion')
```

I want to get order all the topics according to the latest message object attached to that topic.
I executed this query but this does not give the distinct queryset.

```
>> Topic.objects.order_by('-message__pub_date').distinct()
```

Comment: This question appears to be incomplete.  Where is the use of .distinct() that you think does not work?  (It does work, by the way).

Comment: Yeah! correct, I missed it! I added now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find the explanation in the [documentation for `.distinct()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

I would de-normalize by adding a `modified_date` field to the `Topic` model and updating it whenever a Message is saved or deleted.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need distinct() here, what you need is [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation).  This query will do what you want:

```
from django.db.models import Max
Topic.objects.annotate(Max('message__pub_date')).order_by('-message__pub_date__max')
```

Though if this is production code, you'll probably want to follow akaihola's advice and denormalize "last_message_posted" onto the Topic model directly.

Also, there's an error in your default value for Message.pub_date.  As you have it now, whenever you first run the server and this code is loaded, datetime.now() will be executed once and that value will be used as the pub_date for all Messages.  Use this instead to pass the callable itself so it isn't called until each Message is created:

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```