# Remove duplicate in a query based on a specific field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I would like to remove duplicates from a query based on a field.
I don't want to get only the values but also the objects.
The ORM needs to make a choice depending on which row will be removed and which one will be kept.

Let's use this example :

```
name - date - value
chris - 1/1/2012 - 12
youssef - 1/02/2015 - 13
trump - 1/8/2017 - 12
chris - 1/12/2018 - 21
trump - 1/03/2019 - 29
```

The output would be :

```
name - date - value
trump - 1/03/2019 - 29
chris - 1/12/2018 - 21
youssef - 1/02/2015 - 13
```

Basically, i want to remove the duplicates based on date order, something like (it doesn't work) :

```
Table.objects.order_by('-date').distinct('name').order_by('-value')
```

Can the ORM handle this query ? Or should it write a function ?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648545/django-query-with-distinct-and-order-by). It may provide some insight into what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, but i couldn't use it to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution using the ORM.

The only way to solve my problem was to write this function :

```
def remove_duplicate_based_on_date(query):
    name_visited = []
    pk_to_be_deleted = []
    for object in query:
        if not(object.name in name_visited):
            name_visited += [object.name]
        else:
            pk_to_be_deleted += [object.id]
    return pk_to_be_deleted
```

and use it like this :

```
base_query = Table.objects.order_by('-created_at')
pk_to_be_deleted = remove_duplicate_based_on_date(base_query)
base_query.filter(id__in=pk_to_be_deleted).delete()
```