# Django Model Distinct clause

Tags: django

I have a django model query that needs to fetch me the distinct rows from a particular table, but for some reason its not fetching it.

Let me know your inputs

Query

```
Volunteercontacts.objects.order_by('name')- gives me the expected answer ie;ordering by name
Volunteercontacts.objects.order_by('name').distinct('name')- does not eliminate the duplicate
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453477/queryset-api-distinct-does-not-work/460702#460702

Comment: Show us the output. Also, do try reversing the order of the method calls.

Answer (score 1):

You should differentiate between distinct `Volunteercontacts` models and distinct `name` column values.

For  distinct `Volunteercontacts` models you can use distinct(), but in this case has no effect:

```
Volunteercontacts.objects.order_by('name').distinct()
```

For distinct columns values you can use a dictionary or array of [value list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
Volunteercontacts.objects.values_list('name', 
                                      flat=True).order_by('name').distinct()
```

Also, remember that the ability to specify field names in distinct method is only available in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you elaborate why-Volunteercontacts.objects.order_by('name').distinct()
 does not work..The second works as expected

Comment: @user1050619, distinct() in the first example returns distinct rows (even if you had 1000x rows with name: "FOO", they are distinct rows with their own primary key). The second example returns distinct column values.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.4 provides the expected behaviour in the original question (assuming you are using Posgtres):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#distinct